# Transformer/Inductor Bobbin Sizes

Tags: transformer, inductor, design

I have to design a 150 Ampere, 1.5 mH Inductor for a power supply project assigned to me, and off-the-shelf components are to be used. My instructor is insistent on using a transformer Bobbin to wind the conductor around, however wants me to optimize the design to standard bobbins available commercially. My question is, what is the "standard size" per se? Is there a chart, a la wire gauge chart, available for it? I've tried Google but sofar haven't found anything useful. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Pick a core, then pick a bobbin to fit the core. Supplier catalogs will have the information you need.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany that's what I thought. However, the goal to select core based on the Bobbin, which is what is throwing me off a bit. Also, can you name any supplier if that won't be much of a trouble?

Comment: If you don't need anything specialty, distributors like digikey and mouser are probably where you want to look.

Comment: The core cross sectional area (once you've picked the material) and other dimensions will be the most important design parameters so picking the bobbin first makes little sense to me. TDK/Epcos are ferrite core suppliers. Completely different ones for steel cores. The latter have sizes such as EI-48.

Comment: Economy of scale. Standard cores will typically have a bobbin manufacture making. Non-standard won't. You need to determine the core area needed to support your Use case THEN find suitable core manufacturers THEN align with common Bobbi s